# How to change list of list to a string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I need to **get**:

```
'W1NaCl U1NaCl V1NaCl'
```

**from**:

```
[['W1NaCl'], ['U1NaCl'], ['V1NaCl']]
```

How to get required output in `pythonic` way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = [['W1NaCl'], ['U1NaCl'], ['V1NaCl']]
res = " ".join([item[0] for item in items])
```

Which yields: `W1NaCl U1NaCl V1NaCl`

Comment: Really nice and cool!Tomer, God bless you and stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
[[i] for i in 'W1NaCl U1NaCl V1NaCl'.split()]
```

Split will chop it into words, and the list comprehension will make the inner-arrays

Comment: It seems what you suggested need to be reversed.

Comment: Ok, my fault. Note: Usually, posts on Stack Overflow put the input first and expected output last.